# How to left align tabs for TabHost using TabWidget?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-tabhost, tabwidget

The following is my XML layout. I am trying to left align the only tab as seen in the following image (the image has 2 tabs, but I want to align it in the way that it only has "**FOCUSED**" without "**OTHER**" tab)

[image]

**Message_List.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="x.x.x.MessageActivity">

  <TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabHostMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="left"
            ></TabWidget>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabMedication"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/msgListView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                </ListView>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/noMessage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="No Messages"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
 </TabHost>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Currently, i only have 1 tab and it is in the center with white spaces on its left and right.